# How to reduce the time complexity of this problem?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

After having a long difficult coding challenge, there was a problem that bugged me. I thought about it for an adequate time but couldn't find the way to solve it. Here, I am providing a problem and example below.

#### Input

- v : an array of numbers.
- q : 2 dimensional array with 3 elements in nested array.

#### Description

`v` is an array and `q` is a commands that does different thing according to its nested element.

if first element of nested array is `1` => second and third element of the nested array becomes the **index** and it returns `sum[second:third+1]` (As you can see, it is inclusive)

if first element of nested array is `2` => element of second index becomes the third. same as `v[second] = third`

#### Input example

- v : [1,2,3,4,5]
- q : [[1,2,4], [2,3,8], [1,2,4]]

#### Example

With a provided example, it goes like

1. command is `[1,2,4]` => first element is `1`. it should return sum from `v[2]` to `v[4]` (inclusive) => 12.
2. command is `[2,3,8]` => first element is `2`. it switches `v[3]` to **8**. (now v is `[1,2,3,8,5]`)
3. command is `[1,2,4]` => first element is `1`. it should return sum from `v[2]` to `v[4]` (inclusive) => 16, as the third index has been changed from the previous command.

So the final answer is [12, 16]

#### Question.

The code below is how I solved, however, this is O(n**2) complexity. I wonder how I can reduce the time complexity in this case.

I tried making a hash object, but it didn't work. I can't think of a good way to make a cache in this case.

```
function solution(v, q) {
  let answer = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    let [a, b, c] = q[i];
    if (a === 1) {
      let sum = 0;
      for (let i = b; i <= c; i++) {
        sum += v[i];
      }
      answer.push(sum);
    } else if (a === 2) {
      v[b] = c;
    }
  }
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: "*this is `O(n²)` complexity*" - not exactly, no. What is `n`? What complexity was the challenge aiming for?

Comment: Coding challenge questions usually come with a detailed list of input constraints. What are the constraints for this question?

Comment: @trincot You are right. I should fix it. Thanks

Comment: @Bergi Since I used nested iteration, I thought this will work as n**2. (number of v goes to N and q goes N).

Comment: @user3386109 I remember there wasn't a big constraint. elements are all natural number. the only constraint that I couldn't overcome was time complexity.

Comment: @JunKim The lengths of `v` and `q` should be measured as two separate variables. If you said `O(n*m)`, that would make more sense. (And then we might want to incorporate the distributions of the `1` and `2` commands)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of problem can typically be solved more efficiently with a [Fenwick  tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)

Here is an implementation:

```js
class BinaryIndexedTree extends Array {
    constructor(length) {
        super(length + 1);
        this.fill(0);
    }
    add(i, delta) {
        i++; // make index 1-based
        while (i < this.length) {
            this[i] += delta;
            i += i & -i; // add least significant bit
        }
    }
    sumUntil(i) {
        i++; // make index 1-based
        let sum = 0;
        while (i) {
            sum += this[i];
            i -= i & -i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

function solution(values, queries) {
    const tree = new BinaryIndexedTree(values.length);
    values.forEach((value, i) => tree.add(i, value));
    
    const answer = [];
    for (const [a, b, c] of queries) {
        if (a === 1) {
            answer.push(tree.sumUntil(c) - tree.sumUntil(b - 1));
        } else {
            tree.add(b, c - values[b]);
            values[b] = c;
        }
    }
    
    return answer;
}

let answer = solution([1,2,3,4,5], [[1,2,4], [2,3,8], [1,2,4]]);
console.log(answer);
```

### Time Complexity

The time complexity of running `tree.add` or `tree.sumUntil` once is O(log), where  is the size of the input values (`values.length`). So this is also the time complexity of running one query.

- The creation of the tree costs O(), as this is the size of the tree
- The initialisation of the tree with `values` costs O(log), as really each value in the input acts as a query that updates a value from 0 to the actual value.
- Executing the queries costs O(log) where  is the number of queries (`queries.length`)

So in total, we have a time complexity of O( + log + log) = O((+)log)

### Further reading

For more information on Fenwick trees, see [BIT: What is the intuition behind a binary indexed tree and how was it thought about?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10538)

Comment: TIL!  The things you miss when you only had a few CS courses.  I'd never seen Fenwick trees before, and I can see several uses.  Thank you!